# How to create badge with image in sidebar (like in Mail.app)?

Tags: cocoa

I'm creating `NSOutlineView` with custom cell class (extending `NSTextFieldCell`) which should display image-based badge (something like in Mail.app while working offline).

Is this approach appropriate? I've created NSRect with oval shape inside (with `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:xRadius:yRadius`: method) which is filled with color depending if window is active etc. I've prepared a image with a symbol I want to dispay (grey on transparent background) and draw it inside a rect using `drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:` method. I'm able to choose such a `NSCompositingOperation` to have an image displayed properly when background is blue or grey but not on white background.

May it be related to the brightness of the image is (or is it another image-related problem) or maybe should I do something totally different?

Comment: “I'm able to choose such a `NSCompositingOperation` to have an image displayed properly when background is blue or grey but not on white background.” What happens on a white background?

Comment: There was a grey symbol on it while I needed transparency. Finally I've done it using Core Image filter CIBlendWithMask instead with my mask image as inputMaskImage, generated oval shape in appropriate color as inputBackgroundImage and transparency or white color as inputImage. Works nice.